# Function .describe(exclude='number')?

Tags: python

I am just looking at the Titanic Kaggle competition and found this parameter in the .describe() function intriguing. **I've taken a screeshot (highlighted in blue)**. [And this is the link for the notebook.](https://www.kaggle.com/bhatiashivam/ahoy-top-3-the-only-notebook-you-need)

[image]

I have been trying to figure out what it does but can't... what numbers is excluding? I went to pandas documentation but found it unhelpful :(

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html contains a description of the `exclude` argument

Comment: I know. But I still don't get it, that's why I was sharing it on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `exclude="number"` to `df.describe`, pandas excludes all the columns in the dataframe whose data types are subclasses of `numpy.number`, which are:

```
 numpy.clongdouble,
 numpy.complex128,
 numpy.complex64,
 numpy.complexfloating,
 numpy.float16,
 numpy.float32,
 numpy.float64,
 numpy.floating,
 numpy.inexact,
 numpy.int16,
 numpy.int32,
 numpy.int64,
 numpy.int8,
 numpy.intc,
 numpy.integer,
 numpy.longdouble,
 numpy.signedinteger,
 numpy.timedelta64,
 numpy.uint16,
 numpy.uint32,
 numpy.uint64,
 numpy.uint8,
 numpy.uintc,
 numpy.unsignedinteger
```

IOW, only the non-numeric columns remain in the dataframe. This is useful when you want to see only the categorical variables' summary (as in the example you shared) because the non-numeric columns' statistics are not shown in the output of `.describe` by default.

Comment: Ahhh. That makes total sense! Thanks for the help Mustafa.